# Why would dog move her runt puppy to a place by itself after three weeks

Tags: dogs, behavior

Why would a mom dog move the runt of her litter to a place by itself after 3 weeks?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I'd guess she's moved it away because it's less likely to survive and it's "taking" food from the other pups in the litter. You might have to hand feed it if you can't convince her to take it back.

Comment: Also no expert, but I have heard similar anecdotes before.  This is common in the wild, and your domesticated-wolf-descendant is responding to instinct.  There is probably something significantly wrong with this pup beyond merely being the runt.  Forgive the bluntness, but I fear you may not have this pup for much longer- sadly, "mother knows best."

Comment: Hannah, I have no experience on the matter, but welcome to Stack Exchange, and I sincerely hope you'll come back to tell us what does happen with the runt.  Anecdotes and guesses certainly aren't much concrete.  So if nothing else, if you can come back and answer your own question from experience, it will be a more useful answer to people in the future with the same concerns!  Hope it goes well :-)

Comment: The pup is being abandoned.  It will die if you don't hand feed.   It may be ready for food.